# HTML Audio component controls not showing download in Safari

Tags: html, reactjs, safari

I have an audio component declared in React with controls like this:

```html
<audio controls>
  <source src={url} />
</audio>
```

This is working in all the browsers except Safari. When I try to use the audio controls it only appears the speed of the audio (0.5x, 1x, 1.25x, etc...) but there is no download option.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

try  adding more [Media container formats](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Formats/Containers) on order to support more platforms and browsers :

```
 <audio controls>  
      <source src={url} type="audio/mpeg" />    
      <source src={url} type="audio/ogg" />
 </audio>
```

Comment: This answer is off-topic. Adding more media container formats has nothing to do with helping the Download option to appear.

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be *no way* in iOS to get the HTML5 Audio element controls to include a download option. Apple simply doesn't support it, and it doesn't matter if your browser is Safari, Chrome, or Brave; if you're on iOS, you're going have to either supply a simple download link, or add your own Download button.

1. Simple link:

```
    <audio id="myAudio" src="path/to/audiofile.mp3"></audio>
    <a href="path/to/audiofile.mp3" download>Download</a>
```

2. Download button:

```
    <audio id="myAudio" src="path/to/audiofile.mp3"></audio>
    <button onclick="downloadAudio()">Download</button>
    
    <script>
      function downloadAudio() {
        var audio = document.getElementById('myAudio');
        var url = audio.src;
        var a = document.createElement('a');
        a.href = url;
        a.download = 'audiofile.mp3';
        a.click();
      }
    </script>
```